# Post upload files in angular 4 from spring boot?

Tags: json, angular, rest, spring-boot, file-upload

I have an api handle the request to upload file (in spring boot) as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/api/admin/product/{id}/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Product> postUpload(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile imageFile) {
    Product product = productService.findOne(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.upload(product, imageFile),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below is a service to process my requests. How should I fix it to fit the above api?

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductServiceService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/admin/product';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  postUpload(id) {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('image', image);
return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/' + id + '/upload', formdata, this.options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
  errorHandler(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error || 'SERVER ERROR');
  }
}
```

And this is the error after build
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Your **server** must enable CORS (and thus set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the **responses**). Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors. Or just serve your angular app from your Spring boot server, which would make CORS unnecessary.

Comment: I have enable CORS on server and angular app. 
However, it still does not work!

Comment: The error in the console says otherwise. So either you haven't, or you have done it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few of my observations based on the code shared by you:

- `private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});`. This is wrong, Content type should be `multipart/form-data`
- `this._http.get` - this should be `POST`
- File should be associated by `image` request param

I am not familiar with Angular to give you an exact answer.

Update:

If your client application is another Spring Boot application then you can run Zuul proxy on your Angular JS app and map `/api` URL to `http://localhost:8080/api`. Enabling Zuul Proxy is as simple as 
* Adding dependency on `spring-cloud-starter-zuul` in your pom
* annotating the configuration class with `@EnableZuulProxy` 
* Adding following in the properties: `zuul.routes.api.url http://localhost:8080/api`

So from your client app you call the api: `http://localhost:4200/api/admin/product/17/upload` and your client app (using Zuul proxy) will invoke the `http://localhost:8080/api/admin/product/17/upload` at the server.

Comment: I've re-code, but it's still not working, let me revise it.
thank!

Comment: I corrected my problem, by replacing `{'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}` with `{'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data'}`. However, I also thank for your help.